# How to find ppd's in printer-driver-escpr?

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I am installing an Epson XP-830 printer. Openprinting doesn't list it (it's new), but the -820 seems like a close match. (Epson's own website also gives similar if not identical instructions for both.) See below:
http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-XP-820_Series

Open's instructions are to use the driver epson-escpr. I already have printer-driver-escpr, which is the binary of epson- for my distro.

Questions:
- Since I have the "approved" binary, I don't see the need to download the source. Is this reasonable here?
- The binary says it contains .ppd's in compressed form. How do I find them? I intend to use CUPS, but need to find that ppd.